# Polynomial function in $\textbf{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $f:\textbf{R}^3\to\mathbf{R}^3$ be $f(x, y, z)=(x+2y+z,2x+5y+2z,z+2y)$.
I have to find polynomial $p\in\textbf{R}[x,y,z]$ such that $(p\circ f)(x,y,z)=x^2-2y^2+z^3$.
How do I approach this question?

Comment: You've got to combine the powers of the coordinates of $f$ so that you get the desired expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$p(f(x, y, z)) = p(x + 2y + z, 2x + 5y + 2z, z + 2y) = x^2 - 2y^2 + z^3$.

Now, if you take $x + 2y + z = a, ~ 2x + 5y + 2z = b, ~ z + 2y = c$, you see easily that $y = b - 2a, x = a - c, z = c - 2y = c - 2(b - 2a)$. If you plug in the values of $x, y, z$ on the right side of the equation (in terms of $a, b, c$), you'll get a nice expression for $p(a, b, c)$.

Answer (score 0):

Sketch: What's confusing about this problem is that there are two different $x,y,z$'s and they mean different things.  So, it might be easier to write $p\in\mathbb{R}[r,s,t]$.

If $p=r^2+t$, this means that
$$
p\circ f=(x+2y+z)^2+(z+2y)=x^2+4xy+4y^2+2xz+4yz+z^2+z+2y.
$$

Observe that the vector space consisting of polynomials of degree $1$ is three dimensional.  Moreover, $f$'s coordinates consist of three polynomials of degree $1$.  By looking at this a little bit, we see that these three polynomials span the space of polynomials of degree $1$.

Now, we can find a way to write $x$, $y$, and $z$ as linear combinations of the coefficients of $f$.  Finally, square/cube these expressions and multiply by the desired coefficients to get the desired answer.